# how to display backslash in this context for cognito filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-cognito

I have to made a filtering on cognito, and the string needs to be like this

```
"family_name = \"Reddy\""
```

I'm using

```
`email = "\"${email}"\"`
```

and in the console log there is no backslash...but if I'm using double backslash it shows 2 backslashes.. I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Actually.. it works like that

```
`email = \"${email}\"`
```

Thank you anyway!